# python object detection h264 from stream lost frames

Tags: python, error-handling, frame, rtsp, detection

hey i am making a python scrip to detect object from RTSP stream (using h264 decoding)
sometimes i get empty frame.

all the script is in a while "True" and every time i get an empty frame the program breaks.

```
while True:
    (grabbed, frame) = vs.read()
    img = frame
    #frame = frame[1] if args.get("video", False) else frame
    #Breake if empty
    if frame is None:
        print(grabbed, frame)
        **break**
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

i know that the programs exits because of the "break" but when i remove it, the program freezes
what i want to do in  this situation is to skip that frame and get the next.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered to use ``continue`` instead of ``break``?

Comment: yes, i have tried, the problem is that the program freezes after it "continues"